# PHP BB installation

Tags: php, phpbb

I recently installed the phpBB app using the one click function (I have a linux cPanel server). However, it does not send out user registration confirmation emails when they register. I get the error:

Quote:
Errno 2: mail() has been disabled for security reasons at [ROOT]/includes/functions_messenger.php line 1651

Now, I asked the folks at the phpBB forums and they said that this was to do with my web host blocking the mail() function. Why is this and how can I unblock it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try contacting your web-host if they can allow the usage of mail function. If not you can ask them details about SMTP usage. phpBB has support for sending mails via SMTP. You can find the e-mail settings at your control panel. Admin> General> E-mail settings